# MYSQL Explode string into different result

Tags: mysql

I need some help on mysql query

i have a member id string such as |1|2|3|4|, each number represent a member id.
The string is stored in one of the table.

How can i get the result in just using one query 
for example

```
select memberid,name,age,email from member where memberid = explode('|1|2|3|4|')
```

to get 4 member result start from 1 such as below

```
MemberId|name|age|email
1       |    |   |
2       |    |   |
3       |    |   |
4       |    |   |
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you change the way ID is stored in the other table, specifically removing the encapsulating bars: `1|2|3|4` in stead of `|1|2|3|4|5|`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select memberid,name,age,email from member where MemberId = 1 or MemberId = 2 or MemberId = 3 or MemberId = 4 or MemberId = 5
```

or use IN:

```
select memberid,name,age,email from member where MemberId IN(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

store your member id string as `1,2,3,4,5` and use mysql `IN` operator to get the records whose id matches in one of the above id's in a single query as

```
$id='5|3|4|1|2';
$id=explode('|',$id);
sort($id);
$id=implode(',',$id);
select memberid,name,age,email from member where memberid IN($id)
```

Comment: yes!this is what i search for. However can i know issit possible that to sort it base on the string? Which means the string might be 1,5,3,2,1 i wan to result to come out in that sequence.

Comment: @ChongWaiLun add `ORDER BY memberid desc` in the above query to sort the results based on the `memberid` in `descending` order

Comment: erm, i think you might be misunderstand my meaning here. The member id string might be change time to time, it can be 1 2 5 4 3, it cant be either descending or ascending, can i sort it automatically base on how the string is order?

Comment: why you want to sort your string, you can sort your results directly

Comment: the string is actually mean by the sequence of the tree, so i had to display start from the first number and following until to the root

Comment: i changed my answer, use like this

Comment: Chong, you can sort results by predefined values using `FIELD`. For e.g. `ORDER BY FIELD('memberid', $id)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT memberid, name, age, email 
  FROM member 
  WHERE find_in_set(memberid , '1,5,3,2')
  ORDER BY find_in_set(memberid , '1,5,3,2')
```